# Does it matter how much complaints you (only you) have given about some player?

Tags: world-of-warships

One player has written to me after the battle, that he has reported me (complaints) with all the max reports number he has for one day.

I wasnt banned or anything else.

Does it matter if you rerport someone once or 5 times? I mean one battle. And I dont mean the situation where you were reported from different players.

Comment: I don't play World of Warships. But if the moderators of the game are anything like the mods on other online services, they would consider multiple redundant complaints made by user A about something user B allegedly did regarding the same incident as abusive behavior of user A, especially if they don't consider the incident report-worthy. The most likely result is that the mods will handle *the first* report by the book, ignore the rest and warn user A to stop spamming them with unnecessary reports.

Answer (score 3):

WG hasn't given the hard numbers, but you basically need to be reported by a large number of players over a longer period of time, and reports are investigated by staff and not a bot. One salty player will probably not be able to get you in trouble.

Comment: If anything, multiple reports by one player against another is evidence that they are very angry (in a raging-report-fit kind of way) and probably will be ignored. However, I can also see a well-reasoned and cool-headed individual reporting highly abusive behavior by the offending player and that player getting banned - whether the "investigation team" has time for such specific acts of abuse is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

they can waste all their reports on you, but only 1 is deducted from your karma, same for compliments, only one is given regardless of how many times they click it